# Using template variable in Datadog SLO widget

Tags: monitoring, datadog

I have one Datadig dashboard to monitor a particular service. To use the same dashboard for other services, I added a couple of template variables to change the queries in the dashboard. But, I could not use these variables in the query section of Datadog SLO widget.

The following query with variables works in the other type of widgets, but not in the SLO widget.

```
sum:aws.applicationelb.httpcode_target_2xx{$environment,$service}.as_count()
```

Is there a way to use variables in SLO widget too, or not possible because it is in beta version or something?

Comment: At the moment it does not look feasible. The nicest view for SLO seems to be the [SLO page](https://app.datadoghq.com/slo) itself. If you create multiple SLOs based on your user expectations, you would have in a single view all the relevant information to understand your system, drive your strategy and better understand where to invest resources (make a service more reliable, increase number of releases, chaos engineering, etc.). You could also add a note with a link to the filtered SLO view: https://app.datadoghq.com/slo?query=service%3Ayou_service